# Using Nvidia *and* AMD GPUs in a Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit for OpenCL development

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, nvidia, multi-gpu, amd-gpu

I am trying to get a AMD and NVidia GPU to run inside the same Ubuntu 14.04 PC for parallel OpenCL development on both. I had achieved this using Ubuntu 12.04 and the information provided [here](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/) and [here](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-10-12/both-nvidia-gtx-and-amd-radeon-on-linux/). Unfortunately what I did back then, does not work anymore (*never* change a running system...).

My question is, whether someone achieved this, and if so how. Information on this problem is very scarce. The problem is that the libraries and drivers from both clash, when I try to install both at the same time - individually they work fine. Installing from packages you end up in package-dependency-hell and using the binary driver installer from both together didn't work.

Since I am not too familiar with the underlying OpenCL implementations, I am a little "in over my head".

Hope someone can perhaps point me in the right direction. The system is an Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit and the GPUs a Geforce GTX 760 and a Radeon HD 7970.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Do you need both cards to be enabled and execute code concurrently? Or would  partitioning the drive running dual booth be an option?

Comment: Long time. Yes, I need both running at the a same time. Aside from using both for development (where switching is possible but cumbersome), we also want to be able to run our analysis on both at the same time. I have to find a solution for this problem...

Comment: @packoman Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Bob Hey. No, unfortunately I did not. In the end we installed the two GPUs into two different systems, since that made sense at the time.

Comment: Not working for me either; the drivers won't both install. Make sure you can ssh into your machine before trying to switch between gpu brands!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but some possible workarounds:

- you could passthrough one of them to a KVM virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 too, and thus install each card's drivers on a different system, but both running at the same time.
- alternatively, you could try the same but within a chroot instead of a virtual machine. I'm not sure whether this approach would work, but you wouldn't lose any performance due to virtualization. And maybe this way, after some heavy symbolic-linking and bootstrap-scripting, you could even recognize both cards as OpenCL devices from a single system.